# How to pass space separated parameter to shell script without quotation marks?

Tags: bash, shell-script

My bash script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

case "$1" in

    # API platform command
    console)
        check_health
        docker-compose exec php bin/console $2
    ;;

    schema)
        check_health
        docker-compose exec php vendor/bin/schema $2
    ;;
    exec)
        check_health
        docker-compose exec php $2
    ;;   
    *)
      echo -e "You have to specify a command"
      exit 1

esac
exit 0
```

If I will save the script as `bin/run` (`./bin/run`) and set `chmod +x bin/run` I will be able to run commands in following way:

`bin/run console foo:bar`

But if there are any spaces in between required for example `foo:bar --force`

I have to run this command in quotation marks as 
`bin/run console "foo:bar --force"`

Is there a way to make this script neater and get rid of quotation marks?

Comment: Wouldn't a better way be to `shift` and then pass whatever remaining parameters as `"$@"`?

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for. With `${@:2}` it works as intended. Fell free to post the answer.

Comment: Are you quoting `${@:2}`? If not, you're not doing it right. Quotes are *required* because, unfortunately, whitespace is hard-coded in the definition of the shell as separating arguments. You *must* quote it somehow if it is intended to be *part* of an argument.